Using helioseismology what are the equations astrophysicists use to determine the age of the Sun?
Astrophysicists talk about solar models when determining parameters of the Sun. But these models must be built from equations. When explaining to the general public what these equations are would be helpful. Can you tell me an equation using solar frequency spacings to determine the age of the sun?
In Guenther and Demarque (1997) ApJ 484:937-959 section 3.4.1 the authors claim"... specifically, the small spacings are sensitive to the age of the  model...This is because older models have greater mean molecular weights, in the core (greater densities) which leads to lower sound speeds in the core...,hence, lower sound speed gradients, which, in turn, leads to lower p-mode frequency spacings." This description sounds like there is a formulaic relationship between the age of the Sun and small frequency spacings. Can you explain how a model that is written in code can make a prediction about the Sun's age without using a line that reads $t_{\rm Sun}$ is such and such?

That isn't how it works. The age of the Sun is known very accurately using meteoritic material. The age constraints from stellar models are much weaker, with uncertainties of order 10% associated with items like the detailed treatment of convection for example.
Asteroseismology does give model-dependent constraints on age because the interior structure and chemical composition of a star change with time. For example, the core of a main sequence star gradually changes from hydrogen-dominated to helium-dominated. These changes lead to changes in the oscillation frequency spectrum.
The way that these are used to estimate an age is not through an equation but by using stellar models at various ages to predict the frequency spectrum and compare those model spectra with the observed spectra (some details can be found in a review by Lebreton & Montalban 2009). The precisions that can be obtained in the best cases are of order 5-10% for main sequence stars.
To be more specific, whilst there are simple temperature-dependent scaling approximations that can be used between the mass, radius and density of a star and the oscillation frequency at maximum power and the large frequency mode spacing, there are no such scaling relations for stellar age (see Bellinger et al. 2018, who make exactly that point in their Introduction). That is because the scaling approximations for mass and radius etc. assume homology (i.e. a similar internal density/pressure profile) as the Sun. But it is precisely the departure from this homology that is related to age.
Instead, there is a complex relationship between the core fraction of hydrogen/helium and the large and small frequency spacings (also as a function of mass, composition and other stellar parameters). The hydrogen/helium core fraction is then related to the stellar age in a mass-and composition-dependent way.
In terms of a "general public summary" of how it works:
Stars are born from the gravitational collapse of interstellar gas that we measure to be about 73% H and 26% He. As a star gets older, nuclear fusion reactions turn the H into heavier He nuclei at the centre of the star. This changes the stellar structure and produces changes in the characteristics of oscillations of the star - particularly the frequency at which these oscillations have their maximum amplitude and the frequency spacings between different oscillation modes. (Akin to gradually loosening all the strings on a violin). Stellar evolution calculations combined with measurements of its oscillations suggest the Sun has turned about half the H in its core into He and that this would take around 4.8 billion years (give or take about 5%). This age is entirely consistent with the much more precise ages, deduced from radioactive dating, of the oldest minerals found in the Solar System.

Thank you for your answer profrob, but I think I am making a valid point.

@Walter what is your valid point? That there must be a formula age $= f(\Delta \nu_s, ...)$.? You possibly could define an emprical relation using asteroseismology models, but that isn't how the ages are found.

Hello ProfRob, and thank you for your reply. I have read the articles you recommended. Perhaps you find my insistence on wanting a formula for the age of the sun as a little frustrating, but this is far from my goal. I am investigating the manner scientists determine the vast ages of the past and creationists' challenges to these techniques. I would like to address the concerns they might have with radiometric dating of meteorites. So, I thought that a formula age = f(∆v,...) might allay their doubts, and avoid that problem. So you see, I am on your side. Can you rule out such a formula?

A creationist would say that the Sun and its oscillation spectrum were created as they are (6000 years ago or whatever). You may as well argue with a pigeon. @Walter About the best you can do is say the Sun was born from interstellar gas, but seismology shows its internal composition is now half helium. It takes about 4.7 billion years to make that helium, agreeing with the precise radioactivity ages.
